# Do location services not update on someone elses test iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode7

I am not getting background updates on another test iPhone. I have an application built and running fine on my own test iPhone. The simulator works fine as well with testing. Both can keep pulling the location services while in the background. I test this by spitting the lat and long into the debug area. Even when in the background, both spit the lat and long and keep chugging through.

---

When I put it on my roommates iPhone to test it, it does not keep updating in the background. Other than that, it works fine. I went into the development part in his settings and could not find anything there either. Is there something I am missing with allowing an the app to run in the background?

Comment: Did your test user say "OK" to location services?

Comment: I did, and I even uninstalled and reinstalled it just to do it all again. Nothing seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services (should be ON) -> Name of your app (check if you allow using location)*

Comment: Yeah all of that is on. I double checked all of that first thing

Answer (score 0):

Check Background App Refresh setting in Settings/General

[Apple - getting the user's location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html)

> When a user disables the Background App Refresh setting either
>   globally or for your app, the significant-change location service
>   doesn’t relaunch your app. Further, while Background App Refresh is
>   off an app doesn’t receive significant-change or region monitoring
>   events even when it's in the foreground.

Comment: I do have this enabled as well. I feel like it has to be that iPhone does not let unpublished apps do this for a nonlinked xcode phone. While my phone is linked to the app, his is not.

Comment: Maybe something to do with this process for testing? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html